# Math problem: 1+1=0

Tags: mathematics, pattern

See if you can solve this math-problem:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&+&1&=&0\\
2&+&8&=&2\\
2&+&2&=&0\\
9&+&8&=&3\\
3&+&4&=&0\\
6&+&9&=&2\\
0&+&2&=&1\\
9&+&3&=&?
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Best of Luck!

Ps: Here is the [link](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/100250/math-problem-11-0#comment285081_100250) without brakets and [here is one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/100250/math-problem-11-0#comment285080_100250) without latex

Comment: If you can't see the $\LaTeX$(latex) commands It is here in normal symbols:

Comment: 1+1=0
2+8=2
2+2=0
9+8=3
3+4=0
6+9=2
0+2=1
9+3=?

Comment: $1+1=0\\2+8=2\\2+2=0\\9+8=3\\3+4=0\\6+9=2\\0+2=1\\9+3=?$

Comment: I'm sure I've seen this idea on this site before but can't find the dup.

Comment: @hexomino I thought exactly the same, and looked for a good 10 minutes before posting! :) Always tricky when the concept you need to search for is hidden behind a spoiler block rather than present in the original question, as these don't get picked up by Search...

Comment: @hexomino [This](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98399/what-is-a-trinity-number) is the closest I've been able to find - quite a different question using the same general concept at its core. Not convinced it's close enough for a dup...

Comment: @Stiv You've done better than I have, I'd forgotten about this one. I feel like the sum version has come up before too, though. It's no biggie really, it has to be expected that similar ideas will crop up multiple times, well done on answering.

Comment: @hexomino [This](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/5734/5373) is the one you're thinking of (one of the most common [dupe targets](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/5734?lq=1) on PSE), but it doesn't involve sums. Close enough for a dupe? I could go either way really ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determine the algorithm](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5734/determine-the-algorithm) (I feel like this is dupey enough because both questions rely on extracting the number on the right in the same way from some numbers on the left, whether or not there's a $+$ sign in the middle).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is:

> $$9+3=1$$
>  In each case, what's being added together here is the number of 'closed counters' (i.e. the 'holes' in the numbers) *when the numbers are written out on a standard 7-segment calculator display*<sup>1</sup>.  The digit 9 has one closed counter, while 3 has zero. The sum is thus 1.
>
>  <sup>1</sup> *This should rule out any queries surrounding the number '4', which can be considered to have 1 or 0 closed counters in different typefaces.*

Comment: Yes you are right.

Comment: What about the digit $4$?

Comment: Just beat me to it!!!

Comment: Good answer, but then it depends on how one would write the 4, no? Here 3 + 4 = 0, not 1. Maybe that’s just a typo/quirk... (+1)

Comment: @JaapScherphuis I put that down to a font-choice...

Comment: I didn't see your answer

Comment: Lol @JaapScherphuis beat me to it

Comment: @JaapScherphuis You can take it as only closed counters which are round.

Comment: @math -  Can you edit your question (and acknowledge the edit) to choose a font with an open "4".  (P.S. Just seen your latest comment ... I'm not totally convinced ;-)

Comment: @JaapScherphuis El-Guest and others: My latest edit should overcome this issue...

Comment: Does anyone know a openended 4

Comment: Works for me — Internet points for all! Nice answer, @Stiv

Comment: @math Plenty of options in the standard list in MS Office - try something like Bahnschrift, Corbel or Kristen ITC (depending on taste).

Comment: I do love a good rose puzzle like this.

Answer (score 2):

My Math logic

> ```
>  Since 1+1=0 and 2+2=0, I assume that adding the same number gives me zero.
>  We also have 0+2=1, meaning that 0+x=1
>  9+3 = ?, but we know that 9+8=3, so we can reach this form
>  9+3 = ?
>  9+(9+8) = ?
>  9+9+8 = 0+8 = 1
>  Answer 1
> ```

Comment: That's an interesting way of getting the answer *without* finding the pattern.

Comment: Very nice out-of-the-box answer.