# If 123x45 = 1, 22+222=0, 8979:4=5, 56319=2 what is 781-32=?

Tags: number-sequence, formation-of-numbers

If 123x45 = 1, 22+222=0, 8979:4=5, 56319=2 what could be the solution to 781-32=?

Found it on an maths board and became desperate over time.

Comment: Which maths board?

Answer (score 3):

I think that

> 781-32 = 2

Because

> In every equation, we count the number of enclosed regions on the left-hand side to get the answer on the right side. 0,4,6 and 9 each have one enclosed region and 8 has two.

Comment: Oh, wow, and I've been to every realm of math to solve it. Thanks! Is this a popular pattern in puzzles?

Comment: @Guestos Yep! Here's [a similar puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5734/determine-the-algorithm/5735#5735) posted in 2014, nine years ago...

Comment: What do you mean by "enclosed region?" (thanks!)